# EF UpdateRange() not working with deleted child collections

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core

```
public Class Parent
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Child> Children {get;set;}
}
```

```
public Class Child
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int ParentId {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

Say that I have 1 `Parent`, and the `Parent` has 2 `Children`.

```
Parent
-- Id = 1
-- Name = "Mark"

Child 1
-- Id = 1
-- ParentId = 1
-- Name = "Tom"

Child 2
-- Id = 2
-- ParentId = 1
-- Name = "Jack"
```

After making the following changes (Deleted Jack and renamed Tom to Luffy:

```
Parent
-- Id = 1
-- Name = "Mark"

Child 1
-- Id = 1
-- ParentId = 1
-- Name = "Luffy"

Child 2 - Deleted
```

Calling DbContext.ParentDbSet.UpdateRange(Mark) will see that Tom is successfully renamed into Luffy, but Jack remained undeleted.

```
Parent
-- Id = 1
-- Name = "Mark"

Child 1
-- Id = 1
-- ParentId = 1
-- Name = "Luffy"

Child 2
-- Id = 2
-- ParentId = 1
-- Name = "Jack"
```

I get get around this by calling DbContext.ChildDbSet.Remove(Jack) before calling SaveChanges.

However, I am trying to avoid this because by the time I call DbContext.ParentDbSet.UpdateRange(Mark), Jack is already removed from Mark.

Currently I get the old Mark again from the database, compare it with the updated Mark (the one with Jack removed) to find out the deleted `Child` records, and then call RemoveRange(The deleted `Child` records).

This doesn't seem like a good idea...

In brief, I want to achieve the followings before calling SaveChanges():

1. Update Parent
2. Update Parent's Child records that have been changed
3. Delete Parent's Child records that have been deleted
4. Insert Parent's Child records that have been added (p.s. UpdateRange() seems to work with inserting child collections too)

Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: It's important to see the exact code that executes what you describe. All details matter. If you do the changes to an untracked entity, EF never knows about the deletion.

Comment: I'm afraid EF Core does not provide "replace disconnected entity child collection" method out of the box. You have to do it manually (load, compare etc.), or use some 3rd party extension, for instance [Detached Mapper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/#detached-mapper) listed in the official [EF Core Tools & Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/extensions/) page

Comment: Thanks @GertArnold, after removing the AsNoTracking() in my Get function, it is now working!